# SVG graphic could not be rendered. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because "this.boundingBoxes" is null

Tags: svg, fonts, apache-fop

I am using FOP 2.8 and XLST 2 below is the DTD

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions"
                xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-datatypes"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
                xmlns:fox="http://xml.apache.org/fop/extensions"
                xmlns:pre="xalan://org.apache.xalan.Version"
                xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

Now when I am running the fop command it is giving me below error:

```
fop -c /path/to/config/config.xml -xml /path/to/test.xml -xsl /path/to/test.xslt -pdf /path/to/tst.pdf -param img /path/to/param
```

error:

```
[ERROR] FOUserAgent - SVG graphic could not be rendered. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because "this.boundingBoxes" is null <java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because "this.boundingBoxes" is null>java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because "this.boundingBoxes" is null
        at org.apache.fop.fonts.MultiByteFont.getBoundingBox(MultiByteFont.java:212)
        at org.apache.fop.fonts.LazyFont.getBoundingBox(LazyFont.java:305)
        at org.apache.fop.svg.font.FOPGVTGlyphVector.buildBoundingBoxes(FOPGVTGlyphVector.java:435)
        at org.apache.fop.svg.font.FOPGVTGlyphVector.getBoundingBoxes(FOPGVTGlyphVector.java:427)
        at org.apache.fop.svg.font.FOPGVTGlyphVector.getGlyphMetrics(FOPGVTGlyphVector.java:297)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.GlyphLayout.doExplicitGlyphLayout(GlyphLayout.java:1107)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.GlyphLayout.adjustTextSpacing(GlyphLayout.java:1465)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.GlyphLayout.getAdvance2D(GlyphLayout.java:386)
```

SVG section from XSLT:

```
 <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:base="http://example.org/today/"  width="1100" height="1150">
                        <svg:defs>
                            <svg:font-face font-family="Test">
                                <svg:font-face-src>
                                    <svg:font-face-uri href="TestReg.ttf"/>
                                </svg:font-face-src>
                            </svg:font-face>
                        </svg:defs>
                        <svg:text font-family="Test" font-size="150pt" x="38.5" y="654.5" transform="rotate(-76.5,40,407)" textLength="125mm" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs"  style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);fill-opacity:0.3">
                            DRAFT
                        </svg:text>
                    </svg:svg>
```

Please let me know which svg:text  parameter here is causing the issue?

---

### ***Update***                                                   |

Issue was with my configuration file; now it is working fine; one observation with fop-2.8; both of the below code is working:

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object>
  <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:base="http://example.org/today/"  width="1100" height="1150">
     <svg:defs>
      <svg:font-face font-family="TestReg">
       <svg:font-face-src>
         <svg:font-face-uri href="TstReg.ttf"/>
       </svg:font-face-src>
      </svg:font-face>
     </svg:defs>
     <svg:text font-family="TestReg" font-size="150pt" x="68.5" 
        y="354.5" transform="rotate(-46.5,50,350)" textLength="125mm" 
        lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs"  style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);fill- 
        opacity:0.3">
            TEST
       </svg:text>
  </svg:svg>
</fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

---

Now not using svg:defs explicitly seems like fop is able to recognize the defs; by reading my config file that I am passing with -c option

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object>
  <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:base="http://example.org/today/"  width="1100" height="1150">
     <svg:text font-family="TestReg" font-size="150pt" x="68.5" 
          y="354.5" transform="rotate(-46.5,50,350)" textLength="125mm" 
          lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs"  style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);fill- 
          opacity:0.3">
          TEST
      </svg:text>
     </svg:svg>
 </fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

So which syntax is idle for fop-2.8 here?

Comment: @RobertLongson   What will be the fix in that case? lengthAdjust = spacing ? As these two are the only option spacing, spacingAndGlyphs

Comment: @RobertLongson do you have any alternative of SVG?

Comment: I had a similar problem when generating an SVG object with a <text> portion.

The problem ended up being in the definition of the font itself (I was defaulting to an Arial I defined in my fop.xml, which I guess was malformed in someway).

Comment: @TylerMacMillan but here for me same code piece is working with fop-1.1 so not sure where the discrepancy is.