# InvocationTargetException From FontManagerFactory.java While Running XML To PDF Conversion XSLT1.0 FOP2.8 For svg:text

Tags: linux, awt, xslt-1.0, redhat, apache-fop

I am trying to render svg:text as water mark in my pdf below is the simple svg:text that I am trying to render:

```
<xsl:template name="Draft">
 <fo:block-container z-index="-1" position="absolute" right="-20mm">
  <fo:block>
   <fo:instream-foreign-object>
    <svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="157mm" width="190mm">
     <svg:text x="140" y="520" transform="rotate(-46.5,50,350)" textLength="125mm" font-style="fill:rgb(0,0,0);fill-opacity:0.3" font-size="50mm" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">
      DRAFT
     </svg:text>
    </svg:svg>
   </fo:instream-foreign-object>
  </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
</xsl:template>
```

Below is the error that we are getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:87)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:75)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getFontManagerForSGE(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:139)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:173)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:201)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:80)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.DefaultFontFamilyResolver.<clinit>(DefaultFontFamilyResolver.java:86)
        at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG$Loader.createImageInfo(PreloaderSVG.java:165)
        at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG$Loader.getImage(PreloaderSVG.java:131)
        at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG$Loader.access$200(PreloaderSVG.java:108)
        at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG.preloadImage(PreloaderSVG.java:76)
        at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageManager.preloadImage(ImageManager.java:176)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.AbstractIFPainter.drawImageUsingDocument(AbstractIFPainter.java:323)
        at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFPainter.drawImage(PDFPainter.java:290)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderForeignObject(IFRenderer.java:1324)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderInlineViewport(AbstractRenderer.java:1034)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.renderInlineViewport(AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.java:836)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderInlineViewport(IFRenderer.java:860)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderInlineArea(AbstractRenderer.java:877)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderInlineArea(IFRenderer.java:924)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderLineArea(AbstractRenderer.java:845)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlocks(AbstractRenderer.java:704)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlock(AbstractRenderer.java:758)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderBlock(IFRenderer.java:1004)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlocks(AbstractRenderer.java:689)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.renderReferenceArea(AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.java:759)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlock(AbstractRenderer.java:744)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderBlock(IFRenderer.java:1004)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlocks(AbstractRenderer.java:689)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderBlockViewport(IFRenderer.java:809)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlock(AbstractRenderer.java:737)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderBlock(IFRenderer.java:1004)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlocks(AbstractRenderer.java:689)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderRegion(AbstractRenderer.java:418)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderRegionViewport(AbstractRenderer.java:38
```

**Note:**

1. When I am removing this water mark we are able to render the PDF.
2. Also for any other elements inside any block as of now hadn't used any font-family seems those are internally get managed to be converted to UFT-8 encoded characters in order to get rendered.

What is the path forward here?

Thanking you in advance for any fruitful input.

****UPDATE****

Console logs:

From SERVER-1 where it is successful with Draft water mark:

```
[WARN] FOUserAgent - Font "Symbol,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "Symbol,normal,400".
[WARN] FOUserAgent - Font "ZapfDingbats,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "ZapfDingbats,normal,400".
[WARN] FOUserAgent - Font "Arial,normal,400" not found. Substituting with "any,normal,400".
[INFO] FOUserAgent - Rendered page #1.
[INFO] FOUserAgent - Rendered page #2.
[INFO] FOUserAgent - Rendered page #3.
```

From the SERVER-2 where it is failing WITH Draft water mark:

```
Jul 25, 2023 1:15:13 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Font "Symbol,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "Symbol,normal,400".
Jul 25, 2023 1:15:13 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Font "ZapfDingbats,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "ZapfDingbats,normal,400".
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:87)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:75)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getFontManagerForSGE(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:139)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:173)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:201)
        at java.desktop/sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:80)
        at org.apache.batik.bridge.DefaultFontFamilyResolver.<clinit>(DefaultFontFamilyResolver.java:86)
        at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG$Loader.createImageInfo(PreloaderSVG.java:165)
        at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG$Loader.getImage(PreloaderSVG.java:131)
        at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG$Loader.access$200(PreloaderSVG.java:108)
        at org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG.preloadImage(PreloaderSVG.java:76)
        at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageManager.preloadImage(ImageManager.java:176)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.AbstractIFPainter.drawImageUsingDocument(AbstractIFPainter.java:323)
        at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFPainter.drawImage(PDFPainter.java:290)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderForeignObject(IFRenderer.java:1324)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderInlineViewport(AbstractRenderer.java:1034)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.renderInlineViewport(AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.java:836)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderInlineViewport(IFRenderer.java:860)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderInlineArea(AbstractRenderer.java:877)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderInlineArea(IFRenderer.java:924)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderLineArea(AbstractRenderer.java:845)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlocks(AbstractRenderer.java:704)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlock(AbstractRenderer.java:758)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderBlock(IFRenderer.java:1004)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlocks(AbstractRenderer.java:689)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.renderReferenceArea(AbstractPathOrientedRenderer.java:759)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlock(AbstractRenderer.java:744)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderBlock(IFRenderer.java:1004)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlocks(AbstractRenderer.java:689)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderBlockViewport(IFRenderer.java:809)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlock(AbstractRenderer.java:737)
        at org.apache.fop.render.intermediate.IFRenderer.renderBlock(IFRenderer.java:1004)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderBlocks(AbstractRenderer.java:689)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderRegion(AbstractRenderer.java:418)
        at org.apache.fop.render.AbstractRenderer.renderRegionViewport(AbstractRenderer.java:38
```

From the SERVER-2 where it is NOT failing WITH-OUT Draft water mark:

```
Jul 25, 2023 1:15:13 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Font "Symbol,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "Symbol,normal,400".
Jul 25, 2023 1:15:13 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
WARNING: Font "ZapfDingbats,normal,700" not found. Substituting with "ZapfDingbats,normal,400".
INFO: Rendered page #1.
INFO: Rendered page #2.
INFO: Rendered page #3
```

.

Comment: Do the comments in this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75825093/3710053

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed no; that was different issue and it was resolved see updated comment. Here issue is different; code is not having issue I believe as same code IS WORKING in one Linux server and it is NOT WORKING in another Linux server. So probably I am not able figure it out why in another server it is failing.

Comment: So your my fop.xml and the used fonts are on both servers the same?

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed No I am not at all using any font-family ;  you can revalidate my code that I posted. And I believe you are talking about configuration xml; so that is not needed I think when I am not using any font-family.

Comment: @KJ then why that is not happing for both the servers? Like in one of my server the same code is working with out even a font family.

Comment: @KJ it is getting called from page header. I can give you console out put for both cases success(From server 1, from server2 with out draft) and failure (from server2 with draft), had added in the question's update section please check.

Comment: Do you have a `fop.conf` configuration file? Does it have `autodetect` in e.g. `<renderers><renderer mime="application/pdf">..<fonts>..<auto-detect/></fonts></renderer></renderers>`?

Comment: @KJ that is the catch here; ZapfDingbats, Arial, Any all these font-family fop is substituting by default ( I hadn't use font-family any where as element's attribute/property) , so probably I am still back to square one ; what will be the solution here so that I can rendered the pdf with draft on server2  ?

Comment: @MartinHonnen so is that means if we  add <auto-detect/> that will work for my svg:text to render in server 2 as well? I will try that but then why it is not falling in my server 1 ?

Comment: @RitoSarkar, I am not sure that setting will solve your problem but I for sure got around many problems with fonts since I have added it to my `fop.conf` and set up a font cache.

Comment: @MartinHonnen will try that finger crossed .

Comment: @MartinHonnen I tried still having same issue :-(